# Android Studio vertical Format: Place objects on same line

Tags: android, android-studio

I would like to split up my buttons into two rows as it current looks like this:
http://puu.sh/n1Wom/63e06ce96c.png

However whenever I try to move a button up it simply moves the other button down, preventing me from placing two buttons on the same line:

http://puu.sh/n1Wrw/901c2033a3.png

I have the android:orientation="vertical" and I think it has something to do with it, but if I change it to anything else all the buttons disappear.

What would be the best way to go about splitting the buttons into two rows instead of one single long one?

My activity_main.xml code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="">

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:gravity="bottom"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/lowEnergy"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:onClick="low_energy"
        android:text="low energy"
        android:layout_gravity="right" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/stupidPeople"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:onClick="stupid_people"
        android:text="Stupid People"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/rich"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:onClick="rich"
        android:text="I&apos;m Rich"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/wall"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:onClick="wall"
        android:text="Wall"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/the_big_lie"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:onClick="play_the_big_lie"
        android:text="The Big Lie"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/her_stupidity"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:onClick="play_her_stupidity"
        android:text="Her Stupidity"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/sitdown"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:onClick="sitdown"
        android:text="Sit down"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="hold it"
        android:onClick="hold_it"
        android:id="@+id/hold_it"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="coats"
        android:onClick="coats"
        android:id="@+id/coats"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="no action"
        android:onClick="no_action"
        android:id="@+id/noaction"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Bush"
        android:onClick="play_no_bush"
        android:id="@+id/bush"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Hard Time"
        android:onClick="hardtime"
        android:id="@+id/hardtime"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="english"
        android:onClick="english"
        android:id="@+id/english"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="captured"
        android:onClick="captured"
        android:id="@+id/captured"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="losers"
        android:onClick="losers"
        android:id="@+id/losers"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/output"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:textSize="25sp"
        android:background="#ffffff" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm going to assume that you meant you wanted to *columns* of items instead of two *rows*.  A row is a horizontal collection of items.  Column is a horizontal collection.

You can use GridView and GridLayout to achieve a two dimensional set of buttons where you can define as many columns as you need.